# Spring boot application connection to the postgres DB using IAM authentication which is deployed in ECS fargate services

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

Project configuration:
Step 1: pom.xml

```
`<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
`
```

added necessary dependency of aws SFDK

Step 2:

```
`
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<host:port>/<db_name>?useSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=<db_username_iam enabled in DB>
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=840000

spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
`
```

Step 3:

```
`@Configuration
@Order(2)
public class AwsIamAuthenticationConfig extends HikariDataSource {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(AwsIamAuthenticationConfig.class);

    private static String awsAccessKey = "provided key";

    private static String awsSecretKey = "provided key";

  
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        LOGGER.info("getPassword method");
        return getToken();
    }

   
    private String getToken() {
        LOGGER.info("getToken method - starts");
        var region = new DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain().getRegion();
        var hostnamePort = getHostnamePort();
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

        RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator generator = RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator.builder()
            .credentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).region(region).build();

        GetIamAuthTokenRequest request = GetIamAuthTokenRequest.builder().hostname(hostnamePort.getFirst())
            .port(hostnamePort.getSecond()).userName(getUsername()).build();
        LOGGER.info("getToken method - ends");
        return generator.getAuthToken(request);
    }

    private Pair<String, Integer> getHostnamePort() {
        LOGGER.info("getHostnamePort method - ends");
        var slashing = getJdbcUrl().indexOf("//") + 2;
        var sub = getJdbcUrl().substring(slashing, getJdbcUrl().indexOf("/", slashing));
        var splitted = sub.split(":");
        return Pair.of(splitted[0], Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]));
    }
}`
```

Step 4:

```
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public class JpaConfig {
      @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
        @ConditionalOnMissingBean(type = "HikariDataSource")
        public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
            HikariDataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create().type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
            return ds;
        }

    }
```

```
Error:
[  restartedMain]|DEBUG|stics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter|[url=]|[transaction-id=]||Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693) ~[spring-beans-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
```

Comment: im unable to create datasource using the IAM authentication and referred below link also. https://blog.jdriven.com/2021/06/configure-hikari-connection-pool-when-using-rds-iam/     and https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/rds-database-authentication-with-spring-boot-part-2-iam-authentication/. Still its does not work

Comment: Your error is `No bean named 'entityManagerFactory`...do you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency?

Comment: yes, i have the necessary dependency added to the pom.xml

Comment: Well does this work locally? And not on ECS fargate?  That means the Jar you are generating does not have the proper dependencies...open it up and see what is in it.  Probably not a fat jar.

Comment: no, its not creating entityManagerFactory in local as well. then i tried deploying in ECS. even it fails with same error in ECS.

Comment: Why even try deploying to ECS before you got it working locally?

Comment: IAM privileges given to the service which is present in ECS, the policy applied to specific user can interact with service using IAM. it may not work from local.

Comment: Hi All, im writing back to the portal, as im able to create the connection using IAM with postgres db and able to create the connection pooling without server restart.